# Fetching data from two different tables

Tags: mysql

```html
table name->city                         table name->history

id       city                              id          history
----------------                           -----------------------  
1       mumbai                             1      Lorem ipsum Amet
2       delhi                              2      Lorem ipsum Amet
3       chennai
4       patna
5       ranchi
6       noida
```

Expected output:-

```html
     city              hisoty             history_id  
------------------------------------------------------                        
mumbai            Lorem Ipsum Amet          1  
delhi             Lorem Ipsum Amet          2     
chennai
patna
ranchi
noida
```

Please help me with the query to get expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` like

```
select c.city,
coalesce(h.history,''), 
coalesce(h.id,'') as history_id
from city c
left join history h on c.id = h.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

use `SQL left join` for more [LEFT JOIN](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-left-joins.htm)

```
select c.city,
h.history, h.id as history_id
from city c
left join history h on c.id = h.id;
```